# how to find row number of a value

Tags: excel, powershell

I am Importing the values (value1, Value2, Value3 and Value4) 4 values from a CSV file. Then I am opening the Excel file which has many other parameter already filled. Now I am trying to find the matching value of value1 in the column7 and find the row number. Then I am filling the other 3 values to cloumn 12,13 and 14.

I am having problem in finding the row number.

Is the below code right?

```
$ImportedValues = Import-Csv "c:\123.csv"

$ExcelSourceFile = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\fileexcel.xlxs"
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$ExcelSourceObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelSourceObj.Visible = $true
$ExcelWorkbook = $ExcelSourceObj.Workbooks.Open($ExcelSourceFile, 2, $True)
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetName)

foreach ($ImportedValue in $ImportedValues) {
  $value1 = $ImportedValue | select -ExpandProperty Value1
  $value2 = $ImportedValue | select -ExpandProperty Value2
  $value3 = $ImportedValue | select -ExpandProperty Value3
  $value4 = $ImportedValue | select -ExpandProperty Value4

  $i = $ExcelWorkSheet.Column(7).find($value1).row
  $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,12) = $value2
  $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,13) = $value3
  $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,14) = $value4
}
```

Comment: _Is the below code right?_.. Does it get you the results you want? I see some redundancies with assigning your values. What is `$value1` for example

Comment: `.Column(7)` should be [`.Columns(7)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197266.aspx) (plural)

Comment: $value could be name of a person. I am find the person name in 7th column and trying to find the row number and saving it in the $i variable.
So What could be the code to get the row number?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
$ExcelWorkSheet.Columns.item(7).find($value1).row